# PHP shell_exec doesn't execute

Tags: php, shell, elasticsearch, exec, shell-exec

I'm having this huge headache that is making some buttons on my webserver that stops/start/restart my ElasticSearch service when needed.
I've looked up a lot on the internet and not found anything like my problem.

Here is the shell that I'm trying to execute:

```
if(isset($_POST["name"])){

$name = $_POST["name"];

//the script to check the service status of ElasticSearch (which works fine btw)
$status = shell_exec("systemctl status elasticsearch");

//I use a simple regex to get from the above script's output if the status of the service is "running" or not
preg_match("/\bactive\s+\K\S+/", $status, $result);

switch ($name){
    case "start":
        $shell = shell_exec("sh ../../../../scripts/startElasticsearch.sh");
        echo $shell;
        if($result[0] == "(running)"){
            echo "Node started successfully.";
        }
        break;
    case "restart":
        $shell = shell_exec("sh ../../../../scripts/restartElasticsearch.sh");
        echo $shell;
        if($result[0] == "(running)"){
            echo "Node restarted successfully.";
        }
        break;
    case "stop":
        $shell = shell_exec("sh ../../../../scripts/stopElasticsearch.sh");
        echo $shell;
        if($result[0] !== "(running)"){
            echo "Node stopped successfully.";
        }
        break;
}
}
```

This is the shell script of the 3 .sh files that I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
systemctl start elasticsearch

#!/bin/bash
systemctl restart elasticsearch

#!/bin/bash
systemctl stop elasticsearch
```

I've already changed all permissions to execute the shell (like chmod 755 and so on...).

Now here is the trippy part: when I was debugging the execution of the shell, I've tried to `echo` a "Hello World" so I can be sure that my php script was working fine (since `systemctl start/restart/stop elasticsearch` doesn't output anything)
And it worked all fine. I've got the "Hello World" answer from the script on a toast when clicked the button. But nothing else from the 3 scripts above (I was monitoring the service status via Kibana).

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the shell scripts run if you put them in the same directory as the PHP script that calls them? Could it be an `open_basedir` issue because of the location of the scripts? Or perhaps `systemctl` needs a `sudo`?

Comment: Doesn't `systemctl start/stop` need to be run by root? You're running this from the webserver, which doesn't run as root.

Comment: Try adding `2>&1` to the end of your `shell_exec()` commands, so that you'll see the error messages.

Comment: @MrGlass I don't think is an directory issue, since I've tested with a simple `echo` and the script executed normally. I've tried now to run a `sudo` and i've got this error: 

`sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set` 

I've searched a bit to see what is this, and my sudo is set like this using `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo`:
`-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 143192 Set  7  2017 /usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: @Barmar i followed your tip and probably the problem is the user as you said. I've add `2>&1` to the command and got the following error:

`Failed to restart elasticsearch.service: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status elasticsearch.service' for details.`

Comment: The error you are getting may be addressed by giving the user you use for Apache special sudo privileges for the commands you want. Look at this (but be security conscious and only give permissions to the commands you need). https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos

Comment: Now i've tried to grant `apache` privilleges to execute the scripts (i know its risky) with the command `apache All = NOPASSWD: [path/to/scripts]` at `/etc/sudoers` but i'm still getting this error message:

`We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`.

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging, i found [this article](http://www.ethanjoachimeldridge.info/tech-blog/shell_exec-sudo-php-apache) that answered my question. It was only a simple mistake of using `sh` on the script that was causing the problem. Thank you all for your time!